# Download Folder/Directory from EC2 Ubuntu Server Instance using ssh ,putty or scp

Tags: amazon-ec2, server

Hi want to download a folder from ec2 ubuntu server using ssh, putty or scp.

Comment: What have you tried? What difficulty are you having?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Execute the following scp command,

```
scp -r -i <your identity file(.pem)> ubuntu@<yourserverip>:/your/folder/ <your local directory>
```

example,

```
scp -r -i mykeyfile.pem ubuntu@192.168.0.1:/home/ubuntu/myfolder /var/tmp/newfolder
```